# url_absolute error "not compatible with STRSXP" when using submit_form

Tags: r, rvest, httr

I am trying to scrape the http://www.emedexpert.com/lists/brand-generic.shtml web page for brand and generic drug names

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

session <- read_html("http://www.emedexpert.com/lists/brand-generic.shtml")
form1 <- html_form(session)[[2]]
form2 <- set_values(form1, brand = "tylenol")
submit_form(session, form2)
```

however this results in the error message:

```
Error in xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url) : 
        not compatible with STRSXP
```

Therefore, based on this answer to the same error message (["Error: not compatible with STRSXP" on submit_form with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501108))    I added a session$url as follows:

```
session$url <- "http://www.emedexpert.com/lists/brand-generic.shtml"   # added from S.Ov
```

but I still get the same error message. So I tried also adding various permutations of also adding form2$url such as these

```
form2$url    <- "http://www.emedexpert.com/lists/brand-generic.shtml"
form2$url    <- ""
form2$url    <- "/"
submit_form(session, form2)
```

At this point, the error message goes away and I obtain a web page which contain most of the desired web page. However it seems to completely lack the table of brand and generic names.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The table is constructed dynamically, so it's not possible to scrape it via `rvest`. You can use `RSelenium`

Comment: @GGamba How can I tell if a table is constructed dynamically from inspection?

Comment: You infer.. In this specific instance it is quite clear, the page itself says :"The list will refresh itself every time you change the search term.".

Comment: @GGamba  RSelenium is not the answer I wanted to hear. But I thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes @hackR, RSelenium is not always the answer.

```
library(rvest)
url<-"http://www.emedexpert.com/lists/bg.php?myc"
page<-html_session(url)
table<-html_table(read_html(page))[[1]]
```

This could help you I hope.